# toggle image css based on div id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple divs, each with a unique id and image.

I would like to change/toggle the image css based on the div that is clicked on.
Click once and it changes the opacity. Click again and it returns to the original state.

Any ideas on the approach would be appreciated.

```
<div class="card" id="card1"><img src="images/ten.gif" class="icon" /></div>
<div class="card" id="card2"><img src="images/buf.gif" class="icon" /></div>
<div class="card" id="card3"><img src="images/cle.gif" class="icon" /></div>
<div class="card" id="card4"><img src="images/kc.gif" class="icon" /></div>
<div class="card" id="card5"><img src="images/atl.gif" class="icon" /></div>
<div class="card" id="card6"><img src="images/min.gif" class="icon" /></div>
<div class="card" id="card7"><img src="images/nyg.gif" class="icon" /></div>
<div class="card" id="card8"><img src="images/mia.gif" class="icon" /></div>
<div class="card" id="card9"><img src="images/stl.gif" class="icon" /></div>
<div class="card" id="card10"><img src="images/hou.gif" class="icon" /></div>
<div class="card" id="card11"><img src="images/chi.gif" class="icon" /></div>
<div class="card" id="card12"><img src="images/pit.gif" class="icon" /></div>
<div class="card" id="card13"><img src="images/ind.gif" class="icon" /></div>
<div class="card" id="card14"><img src="images/no.gif" class="icon" /></div>
```

...etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a nice animated effect purely from jquery, so no need for extra css...

```
$(".card").toggle(function() {
    $(this).find("img").animate({ opacity: 0.25 });
},
function() {
    $(this).find("img").animate({ opacity: 1 });
});
```

It just toggles the opacity - 0.25 for first click, 1 for next click, 0.25 for next click etc..

Here's a working example...

http://jsfiddle.net/uHpqf/1/

Comment: Archer, Thanks. This is almost exactly what I was looking for. The only issue is if I animate the containing div instead of the image, then the transparency messes up my border; it also becomes transparent. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: @relyt There you go mate - I've modified both the code and the example.  If you need anything explaining just shout.

Answer (score 3):

If you use code such as:

```
$(".card").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".icon").toggleClass("transparent");
});
```

then you can define a CSS class `.transparent` that has whatever style you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.card').toggle(function(){
       $(this).children('icon').css('opacity','0.5');
    }, function(){
       $(this).children('icon').css('opacity','1');
    });
});
```

If you want to animate the effect:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.card').toggle(function(){
       $(this).children('icon').animate({'opacity':0.5},500);
    }, function(){
       $(this).children('icon').animate({'opacity':1},500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `.toggle` only works in limited ways, but you can use the ternary operator and some jiggery pokery to make it work - this is an option if you either can't or don't want to create a new CSS class.

```
$('.card').click(function ()
{
    $('.icon', this).css( 'opacity', (parseFloat($('.icon', this).css('opacity')) == 0.5 ? 1 : 0.5) );
}
```

Comment: jiggery pokery?! hah, interesting.